# SharePoint Serach Rest API How to get People column value by email or User Id

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-rest-api, search-api

I'm using SharePoint Serach Rest API to get CreatedBy column data, Where I have used Name in Query text

```
Var searchdata = {

{

'__metadata': {
      'type': 'Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.REST.SearchRequest'
   },

  'Querytext': 'QueryText',

}

QueryText: 'CreatedBy: 'Akshay'
```

Here I'm able to get the results using Name, but I wanted to get the Createdby column data using Email address or use Id

Answer (score 0):

Try using below property in your query:

```
AuthorOWSUSER: { <Email Address> }
```